# WooCommerce on order complete - set user role to

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Can't seem to find the answer or where to look for this question but maybe someone who has been down this route will know.

On a successfully WooCommerce order I just want to add some extra code to set the role of the User who made the order to "paid member".

So it will just update row of dbname_capabilities (in dbname_usermeta) where the user_id = the user_id and set it to a:1:{s:10:"paidmember";b:1;}.

The idea of this is then that member will then have access to certain pages on the site after he has paid automatically.

Thanks for any help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to hook into `woocommerce_thankyou` function. Here you can use the default wordpress function `wp_update_user`:http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_user

I hope this gets you on the right track.

Comment: Thanks danyo... definitely giving me something to go from. Thanks

Comment: No problem. If you get stuck give me a shout!

Comment: I used: update_user_meta($user_id, 'wpgog_capabilities', $role); in my hook but for some reason it fails to update.

Comment: what is $user_id? Does it contain the current users id?

Comment: @user1936399 if you came up with a complete solution, it'd be cool if you could post it.